# How do I coordinate settings between my ASP.NET MVC 3 app and SpecFlow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, specflow

So I have a VS 2010 solution containing one ASP.NET MVC 3 project and one SpecFlow project (with NUnit as test runner) to test the former. When testing under SpecFlow (by running the SpecFlow project), I'd like to change a parameter in the MVC application's *ConfigurationManager.AppSettings* dictionary, to make it connect to a test database. This change does not seem to affect the running app however, so I guess the test and the app do not share state.

How can I share this application setting between the MVC app project and the SpecFlow project, so they use the same database?

**Edit:**
I found that the problem wasn't really one of sharing settings between projects (MVC and SpecFlow), but rather between two processes. The reason is that I test MVC via WatiN, which means that the development server, running in a process of its own, is being exercised by the tests. As such the premise of my original question was wrong from the onset, and I consider Jason's answer valid given the original premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test project (SpecFlow) create a new app.config (unless it's already there) and add the `appSettings` section to that, with your test database connection string. IIRC the website will hopefully pick up the connection string from the `appSettings` of the test project, rather then the website.

Comment: If I add the setting to appSettings in the test project's app.config file, will the setting be applied to the MVC app project as well??

Comment: Well, I just tested editing the test project's app.config file and apparently it doesn't affect the app project which is what I'm after. Also, I'd much rather be able to define the setting dynamically in the test setup logic. Not sure how I'd go about it statically (in app.config), since currently at least the database location depends on some runtime parameters.

Comment: Could you use the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"] = "blah";` in your test setup code? At least then you can dynamically set the connection string for your tests.

Comment: Well, that's the approach I describe having originally tried in my question. The problem is that the test code apparently does not share state with the MVC app code, since the MVC app code isn't affected by the changed setting. Also, I can't set breakpoints in the app code while debugging the tests, so it appears that the app runs in a different process.

Comment: I think I've realized why test and application code does not share state; I'm using WatiN, so the tests are exercising my development server, as opposed to loading my app code as a library, which I guess is the normal unit testing approach. Therefore test and app logic are totally decoupled at runtime, and must be configured individually I suppose.